# Opencart Shopping Cart button not working

Tags: opencart, shopping-cart

I am using OpenCart Version 1.5.4.

You can find my dev site here:

```
http://50.87.186.42/
```

My problem is that when I click on the Green Shopping Cart button under the logo on the home page (or in the header on the sub pages) the shopping cart drops down for a split second (if you have items in there they will show, if not it will say that it is empty) and then both the short drop down menu and the button disappear. This happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

Can help me find out why this may be happening?

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are getting an error in the ajax cart code.

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function getOptionSpecialProductId() on a non-object in /home1/garrysun/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_controller_module_cart.php on line 64
```

The most likely cause is a vQmod file that's affecting the specials/options